# Perl, subroutine override with call to its parent | reference

Tags: perl, overriding

I write a Perl module which will be loaded from a main script. This module makes use of subroutines which are defined within the main script (where I'm not the maintainer).

For one of the subroutines in the main script an extension is required but I don't want to patch the main script. Instead I want to override the function within my module and save a reference to the original subroutine. If the override is called, I want to call the original subroutine and then do some additional processing (if required).

sympolic module code

```
my $referenceToOriginalSub;

sub inititialize()
{
    $referenceToOriginalSub = \&originalSub;
    undef &originalSub;
    *originalSub = \&overrideSub;
}

sub overrideSub()
{
    #call original within mainscript
    &$referenceToOriginalSub(@_);
    # do some additional processing if required
}
```

That doesn't work because it ends up with infinite recursion. Obviously the reference to `originalSub` also points to its substitution.

So, could you please point me in the right direction how to avoid infinite recursion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a main program of

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MyModule;

sub mainsub {
  print "Original mainsub\n";
}

mainsub;
```

and with `MyModule.pm` containing

```
package MyModule;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $referenceToOriginalSub;

sub overrideSub {
  print "Override: enter\n";

  $referenceToOriginalSub->(@_);
  # alternative:
  # goto $referenceToOriginalSub;

  print "Override: leave\n";
}

INIT {
  no warnings 'redefine';
  $referenceToOriginalSub = \&main::mainsub;
  *main::mainsub = \&overrideSub;
}

1;
```

The `INIT` block runs just before the runtime begins execution of your program. Doing so allows `use MyModule` to come before the definition of `mainsub` in the main program and still be able to grab a handle on whatever the sub winds up being.

You would use [`goto $referenceToOriginalSub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html) if you are concerned about masking side effects in the call stack, but this allows the execute-before pattern only—not execute-after or execute-around.

Output:

```
Override: enter
Original mainsub
Override: leave
```

Comment: works perfect. Because the main script utilize some sort of dynamic loading I had to move the init block into a initialization sub. Theres one tiny side effect I cant resolve so far. The main script allows a reload of my module (unload and load again). In this case the first substitution (override) take in place and a second will be added on top. Because there is no destructor which will be called I think there is no way to get around.